# Populate map with Points of Interest markers around route

Tags: android, dictionary, routes, location

I draw routes on my google map using next code:

```
private void drawRoute(List<Route> route) {

    for (int i = route.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        final Route currentRoute = route.get(i);


        final PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polyOptions.color(Color.parseColor(allColors[inc_color]));
        polyOptions.width(10);
        polyOptions.addAll(currentRoute.getPoints());
        mMap.addPolyline(polyOptions);

    }
}
```

After this step I want to get from my SQLite database all PoI that are at max 5 km far from my routes and to draw them on map.

How can I filter my database as result to show all locations that are located at max 5 km along the route?

Maybe getting the bounds of route?